# Coordinate axes transformation

Tags: coordinate-systems, geometric-transformation

I'm trying to transform from regular math coordinates to computer pixel coordinates as shown.

1) Each unit on left system equals $20$ units in right system.
2) On left system, the origin is at center, that is at $(100, 100)$ in pixel coordinates. On right system the origin is at top left corner.

[image]
By trial and error I managed to arrive at below formulas :
$$(x,y) \to (20x+100, -20y+100)$$

But I'm finding it a bit hard to explain myself why they work. For example, if I try to interpret the `y transformation` as $-20(y-10)$ I feel lost. Could some kind soul dumb it down for me please. Appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transformation is a sequence of 3 steps:

1) Shift the origin to $(5,-5)$:
$$\begin{align}x'=x+5\\y'=y-5.\end{align}$$
2) Scale by 20:
$$\begin{align}x''=20x'\\y''=20y'.\end{align}$$
3) Flip along the $y$-axis:
$$\begin{align}x'''=x''\\y'''=-y''.\end{align}$$
Combining all 3 steps you get
$$\begin{align}x'''=20(x+5)\\y'''=-20(y-5)\end{align}$$
as desired.

P.S. And of course, $-20y+100=-20(y-\mathbf{5})$ ;-).

Comment: If i reverse your steps. 1) First flip y axis:  $(x, -y)$. 2) then, scale by `20`:  $(20x, -20y)$. 3) then, translate the origin to `(5, -5)` : $(20(x+5), -20(y-5))$

Comment: Beautiful! Doing it in steps helped see it clearly. Thank you so much :)